# How to conduct series of ADF tests on data in correct way?

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

I was trying to fit an ARMA model for some data. It was easy to spot that data is non-stationary, so I decided to conduct ADF test on it and it turns out that I was right. Then I took the first differences of the data and conduct the ADF test on new set of data, and according to the test, the data was still non-stationary. I have also checked the second differences of the data and they were stationary. That brings me to my question, is my reasoning correct? I have read somewhere that is not correct. Can somebody share their knowledge about this topic?

Comment: Very good question. One of me favorites. Reading this every night before sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ADF test results confusion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142003/adf-test-results-confusion) provides clarity as to what is being tested with the ADF test . With all statistical tests one has to know precisely what the null hypothesis is and what the alternative hypothesis is.

The cause/remedy for non-stationarity can occur in a number of ways requiring identification and remediation/treatmewnt.

There could be the need to difference , detrend , demean , filter via arma, adjust for latent deterministic structure such as pulses/level/step shifts/seasonal pulses, segment the data based upon parameter or error variance changes over time to name a few.

Take a look at this rather straightforward question [How to remove non-stationarity?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/456064/how-to-remove-non-stationarity/456204#456204) where the OP asked the direct question of what was needed to make his series stationary. In other words what equation/filter was sufficient to decompose the observed data to signal and noise

Comment: Thank you for your answer, especially for the links, they gave me a lot of information.